# Intersection of circle and polygons

Tags: python, geospatial, shapely

I have a few polygons representing streets (the blue stuff on the image below). I also have a circle (a point with a buffer, the orange stuff on the picture). I would like to find all the portions of streets inside the circle.

[image: map1]

So far, I have something like this:

```py
from myproject import geometry as geo
...
# Load the streets of my city and build a tree
# The city is just a bunch of polygons
city = geo.load_geojson("my_city.geojson")
tree = shapely.STRtree(city)

# Generate the circle
center = shapely.Point(x, y)
circle = geo.generate_circle_around_point(center, radius)

# Find the streets intersecting the circle, then compute the intersections
shapes = [city[idx].intersection(circle) for idx in tree.query(circle)]
```

However, this code only gives me intersections of poor quality (you can see I'm missing some pieces of the streets that I would expect to be within the circle):

[image]

Any idea what could cause this phenomenon?

EDIT:

here is how I generate the orange circle. I have to do it because since I use GPS coordinates, I need to convert the radius from meters to degrees:

```py
def generate_circle_around_point(point: shapely.Point, radius: int) -> shapely.Polygon:
    # Define a projection using a local projected coordinate system
    local_projection = pyproj.Proj(proj="utm", zone=18, ellps="WGS84")

    # Define a function to convert GPS coordinates to the local projected coordinate
    # system
    to_local_projection = partial(
        pyproj.transform, pyproj.CRS("EPSG:4326"), local_projection
    )

    # Transform the center point to the local projected coordinate system
    center_point_local = shapely.ops.transform(to_local_projection, point)

    # Create a circle buffer around the center point with the given radius
    circle_buffer = center_point_local.buffer(radius, resolution=200)

    # Transform the circle buffer back to GPS coordinates
    to_gps_projection = partial(
        pyproj.transform, local_projection, pyproj.CRS("EPSG:4326")
    )
    circle_buffer_gps = shapely.ops.transform(to_gps_projection, circle_buffer)

    return circle_buffer_gps
```

Comment: What is the frequency of points that draw the streets here? You may have few points to generate an accurate intersection.

Comment: The streets were originally LineStrings that I buffered with default parameters, I didn't fiddle with the frequency of points. Could be tha, I'll try. Any suggestion about the frequency I should use?

Comment: As high as possible. Depends on the accuracy you require. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency would fit this problem example.

Comment: Looking at the chopped-off ends of the streets, it looks like they have been intersected with an ellipse, which makes me suspect a map projection problem. What coordinate system are you working in?

Comment: Ah very good eye, that could make sense. It probably comes from where I generate the orange circle. I added the function I use to make it, would you mind having a look please?

Comment: Is zone 18N the correct zone to use here? Are you within [that zone](https://epsg.io/32618)?

Comment: No I'm in London, so it should be zone 30. I just tried with zone 30 and I'm still getting the same output

Comment: Ok I found a better way to generate the circle: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/289923/213279. With this the code above works perfectly. Thanks for putting me on the way with the ellipse, @TurePålsson!